# How to catch the event when none of checkboxes from group is checked or at least one checkbox is checked and then add a class for the related div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

```
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a href="#collapse" data-parent="#accordionQuiz" data-toggle="collapse1.." class="accordion-toggle">
        <strong>1...</strong>
        Question
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapse1..">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="1..@1.." class="control-label">A..</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="FirstAnswer" name="1..@1.." id="1..@1..">
                    content
                    </label>
                </div><!-- /.controls -->
            </div><!-- /.control-group -->

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="2..@2.." class="control-label">B..</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="SecondAnswer" name="2..@2.." id="2..@2..">
                    content
                    </label>
                </div><!-- /.controls -->
            </div><!-- /.control-group -->

        </div><!-- /.accordion-inner -->
    </div><!-- /.accordion-body collapse .. -->
</div><!-- /.accordion-group -->
```

---

Above code is a piece of Quiz form and is repeating for every question. It looks like: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWGBn.png)

---

How to catch the event when none of question-related-checkboxes is checked or at least one is checked and then add a class for the *div.accordion-heading*?

Something like: none is checked - *empty*, at least one - *not-empty*.

There'll be diferent colours and it'll be very useful feature for user to come back to the question which he skiped becouse only one is visible at a time.

I tried do this by myself but I've just started to learn jQuery and... I give up. Perhaps this is a job for mighty AJAX?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do but you can try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/G9rz7/

Comment: Thanks everyone! The working solution is here: **[jsfiddle.net/YsnfC/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/YsnfC/1/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple to accomplish this with the following steps:

1. Register an event for `click` on all checkbox.
2. On each `click` count how many checkbox were checked in group.
3. Then take an action base on the number of checked checkboxes.

The `JavaScript` code looks like this, which can be *optimized*.

```
$('.accordion-group :checkbox').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $group = $this.parents('.accordion-group:first');
    var $checkboxes = $group.find(':checkbox');
    var checks = 0;
    $checkboxes.each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            checks++;
        }
    });
    console.log(checks);

    var $heading = $group.find('.accordion-heading');

    if (checks === 0)
        $heading.removeClass('not-empty').addClass('empty');
    else
        $heading.removeClass('empty').addClass('not-empty');
});​
```

I made a demo at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W2XD2/

---

**EDITS**

I optimized the script to be more specific, and optimize it:

```
$('.accordion-group :checkbox').click(function() {
    var $group = $(this).parents('.accordion-group:first');
    var checks = $group.find(':checked').length;    
    var $heading = $group.find('.accordion-heading');

    if (checks === 0)
        $heading.removeClass('not-empty').addClass('empty');
    else
        $heading.removeClass('empty').addClass('not-empty');
});​
```

You can check the updated revision at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W2XD2/1/

Comment: Rubens's answer was the greatest. I love buddy ;) jQuery is so awesome! Thanks everybody for your solutions but as said Rubens was the most accurate.

Here is my working code now: **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/YsnfC/1/)**

I've just added this code for reset button:

    `$('button[type=reset]').click(function() {
        $heading.removeClass('not-empty').addClass('empty');
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't error check this at all, but here's how I'd do it! I'm sure you can optimize it for your actual application

```
function validateGroup( groupID )
   {
   var valid = 0;
   var $group = $('#' + groupID)

   $group.find(':checkbox').each( function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')
         {
         valid = 1;
         }
      });

   if (!valid)
      {
      $group.addClass("NotValid");
      }
   }
```

Comment: Andrew, you can reduce some LOC by doing this instead `var valid = $group.find(':checked').length > 0`.

Comment: Oh I'm sure I could trim it down, but this seemed a little bit more human-readable for someone who just started learning jQuery! Thanks though!

Comment: I agreed with you Andrew! Some coders like me are *maniac* at reducing code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want to trigger the event.

If you want to do the checking on save or on clicking the next accordion heading you might want to do this:

```
    $(".b_save").click(function() {  
//change the above to $(".accordion-heading") if that is what you trigger the event with
     $.each($(".accordion-group"), function() {
      cls = $(this).find(":checked").length? "#00b5f8":"#ff0000";
      $(this).find(".accordion-heading").css("background-color", cls);
      })
    })
```

If you want to change the color when you click on the checkbox this is the code:

```
$(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
      parentEl = $(this).closest(".accordion-group");
      cls = $(parentEl).find(":checked").length?"#00b5f8":"#ff0000";
      $(parentEl).find(".accordion-heading").css("background-color", cls);
     })


})
```